# 1 samba share not working

Tags: server, samba

Using Ubuntu server 16.04 with only samba selected at install.  After install I installed and configured openssh server to only allow key authentication.  When configuring samba file I made all recommended changes and user authentication is set as well as a samba pw for user and they are same as windows user.  I also added 2 folders and checked permissions on both after a chmod 777 and then add them to end of samba config file the exact same way.  Both show on my win7 pc under the file server but only one is accessible.  The other says can't find path.  I have redone this and dbl checked typos.  They are set up identical yet one is not found yet seen in the file server from Windows.  I even tried to manually map using ip as I read other places.  Any ideas why I have this issue with one folder?  I'd attach files but on my phone ATM, hopefully I can get an answer without providing the whole config file and permissions screenshots, in

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The default ubuntu server does not put you in home dir when you log in so a path relative to that won't work in samba config. 
I added /home/myusername before the rest f the share path and it worked.  This doesn't really explain why the other folder works with a relative path so any insight would still be enlightening